# Palindrome Matrix for the given n number

Tags: python-3.x

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcHJQ.png)How do I create a 2*n+1 matrix as mentioned below:
Input:
1
Output:
1 2 1
2 1 2
1 2 1

Input:
2
Output:
1 2 3 2 1
2 3 1 3 2
3 1 2 1 3
2 3 1 3 2
1 2 3 2 1

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to ask your programming-related question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: plz see the img for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I had this code written. Hope it helps, just create a first row and then use that as reference for adding new rows.

```
INPUT = 3
MATRIX_DIM = (2 * INPUT) + 1

palindorme_matrix = []

current_value = 1
current_row = []
for idx in range(MATRIX_DIM):
    current_row.append(current_value)
    if idx >= (INPUT):
        current_value -= 1
    else:
        current_value += 1
palindorme_matrix.append(current_row)

for row in range(1, MATRIX_DIM):
    new_row = current_row.copy()
    for i in range(len(current_row)):
        new_row[i] += 1
        if new_row[i] > (INPUT + 1):
            new_row[i] = 1
    palindorme_matrix.append(new_row)
    current_row = new_row.copy()

print("Palindrome Matrix ", palindorme_matrix)
```